# x32dbg debugging from map section

Tags: debugging

I'm begginer in x32dbg.
I tried to find a sentence in reference strings but it didn't appeear, so i tried in map sections and i finally found it. But now, i can't put breakpoint, x32dbg says that it is not an executable adress.

What is the procedure to reverse from there ?

I tried to find a string reference in all modules , but nothing founded.
I found the string in map section
In CPU disassembly windows, the adress is:
02476463 | 005400 68                | add byte ptr ds:[eax+eax+68],dl                |
I cannot put a breakpoint on it => not an executable adress